# Console error in Angular 10 when page loads

Tags: angular, primeng, angular10, primeng-menu

I am preparing an array like the below when my page load (ngOnInit() method). But when the page loads I am getting an error in console as

**ERROR Error: Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.**

which is not happening with Angular earlier versions.

I am using primeng to display the data on html

How can I prepare the arrays which will not get the console error.

Thanks in advance.

```html
<p-megaMenu [model]="infoItems" (click)="click($event)"></p-megaMenu>
```

```js
import { MenuItem } from 'primeng/api'

infoItems: MenuItem[];

this.infoItems = [
    { 
       label: 'Configuration Data', 
       icon: 'fa fa-fw icon-configuration', 
       items: [
          { label: 'Preview Configuration'}, { label: 'Configuration label' }
       ] 
    } 
 ];
```

Comment: how's the variables initialized? items: any; or items = [];

Comment: Initialization and import of primeng module is added to the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on **[PrimeNg's Mega Menu Documentation](https://primefaces.org/primeng/showcase/#/megamenu)**, seems like you forgot to put an inner array `[]` inside your `items`.

BUT, have noticed, on your template you are using `MegaMenuItem` but on your component, you are using the `MenuItem` type

You can choose any of these samples if you want to use either of those

**1.) MegaMenuItem**

```
<p-megaMenu [model]="infoItems" (click)="click($event)"></p-megaMenu>
```

```
infoItems: MegaMenuItem[];

this.infoItems = [
  {
    label: 'Configuration Data',
    icon: 'fa fa-fw icon-configuration',
    items: [ [ { label: 'Preview Configuration'}, { label: 'Configuration label' }  ] ]
  }
];
```

**2.) MenuItem**

If you want to use `MenuItem`, you don't have to change anything in your data, instead change your template instead:

```
<p-menu [model]="infoItems" (click)="click($event)"></p-menu>
```

Comment: I am getting this error if I put the inner array inside items. Type '[{ label: string; }, { label: string; }]' has no properties in common with type 'MenuItem'.ts(2559)

Comment: Have updated my answer above. Seems like you want to use MenuItem but in your template you are using MegaMenuItem

Comment: @User no problem :) hoping you can mark the answer as the accepted one as well, that would be very much appreciated. Thank you very much!